# Помогите с парсингом, пожалуйста

Tags: php

Есть такой HTML шаблон:

...

```
<tr>
                                            <td>





        (.+?)




                                            </td>
                                            <td><span class="pull-right muted">
```

...

Вопрос, как обработать пробелы? Парсинг через preg_match_all. Мануалы что-то не помогли.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Конструкция `\s*` совпадет с любым количеством пробельных символов.

Comment: Ага, в `<span class=` это действительно поможет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

@VladD уже [BFG9000](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFG9000) вытаскивает, точно говорю.

Регулярками такое лучше не парсить.
Возьми любой парсер HTML, например [этот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176635/) and be happy!

Answer (score 0):

Что значит "обработать"? Улучшить читаемость человеком? Можно заменить на 1 пробел или убрать совсем:

```
$text =  preg_replace("/\s{2,}/",' ',$text);
```

Comment: Вы некорректно обработаете `<pre>a  b c   d</pre>`.